# Resizing an SVG to specific dimensions

Tags: css, html, svg

I am trying to resize an svg to the exact size which I want it (32x32).
Look at the example at http://jsfiddle.net/Uy94k/6/

This fiddle is a short outtake of a larger .svg file which I include in my html file and refeer to which image I want using:

```
<svg class="small" viewBox="0 0 512 512" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <g filter="">
        <use xlink:href="#login"></use>
    </g>
</svg>
```

(Any easier way to do this by the way?).

As you can see, I've tried using preserveAspectRatio, but without luck. I've also tried different styling techniques (ie. sizing in span tags outside the svn, styling in the svn tags, fiddling with height both in  and where I call it by id.).

If you use a developer tool to look at the height/width of the images in the fiddle, you will see that it is 26x20.. But why is that?

Comment: I'm seeing the images as 32x32... Using Chrome on Win7 **EDIT** Nevermind, I see it now, the `svg` tag is 32x32 but the `path` is 26x20

Comment: Here is a link describing how they changed the dimensions. They used the svg as a background image. Hope it helps! [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Scaling_of_SVG_backgrounds#Specifying_fixed_lengths_for_both_dimensions)

Comment: But how can I use them as background images when I need to "bundle" them in one svg file and refeer to them with id?

Comment: HTMNL has no facility to position a background using the id of an SVG element (obviously).  You'll just have to refer to it the standard way with background-image and background-position.  Unless, that is, you want to fiddle with the SVG using JS.

Answer (score 0):

Tweeking the `viewBox` values (guessing the value of `viewBox="120 70 340 340"` in this case) kinda did the trick. But it is error prone, not nice, and tedious to tweek the parameters.. Look at the example at http://jsfiddle.net/veZSX/1/ for a tweeked vs untweeked version.
There must be a better way?

Comment: If I open the svg in inkscape and click the path I want the viewbox on, inkscape displays it for the selected element! I can just "steal" the correct viewbox from inkscape.. The last 2 parameters in viewbox should be rounded up to nearest whole number instead of down..